# Minecraft mine cart troubles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am attempting to make a MC roller coaster -witch I have done before- and for some reason when I power the tracks, the mine cart shakes back and forth and won't move forward or let me ride in it. I currently am playing 1.8.8 for the PC

Comment: Is the Minecart bouncing off of two blocks? Is it shaking as in going along the rail, or as in shaking side to side?

Comment: Are you sure you're using powered rails instead of activator rails?

Comment: Alternatively, what button are you pushing to try to get in the cart? Left click attacks and causes the minecart to shake back and forth until it breaks into a pickup. Right click is what you use to get in (by default).

Comment: @DGarvanski you should make that into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the 1.8 update [powered rails](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail) and [activator rails](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Activator_rail) behave differently when used for powering a mine cart track. Using activator rails causes shaking and, sometimes, ejects the player character from the mine cart. You only need the activator rails to *activate* carts, but they shouldn't be used continuously. Powered rails should be used for increasing or decreasing speed.

As provided by **Mystery**, here is a video demonstrating the changes made to mine carts and the usage of different rails:

Comment: Maybe include this link in your answer: https://youtu.be/nW67NTP7sro In the video, the changes to minecarts are shown. Also it covers the "bouncing back and fourth", Kirklandish mentioned